# iPhone view with pop up animation?

Tags: iphone, animation, view

I'm new to iPhone development, its going OK so far, I've managed to get to grips with the Tab bar, navigation bar and tableviews.

However I want to be able to copy what the settings app does on the device when a user wants to change language.

In Settings, General, International when a user clicks on Language a new screen animates over the previous screen with a navigation bar that has a cancel and done button and a table view showing the languages available for selection.

I cant seem to find how to do this via Google so I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction of a tutorial or what I should be searching for? Is it type of view or a certain way to animate a view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done via a method available on [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (and thus all of its derivatives as well) called `- presentModalViewController:animated:`. You simply need to create a new view controller that you want to display and pass it into that.

See the link to the `UIViewController` docs above for more info and the complementary method `- dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` to close the view. The docs have links to example code on how to use them as well.

Answer (score 2):

in iPhone, it's done through modal view controller. Refer  [this](http://timneill.net/2010/09/modal-view-controller-example-part-1/) tutorial.